# Can step functions wait on a static website?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway, aws-step-functions

If I deploy a static website with s3 and api gateway, is there any way for a step function to wait for some activity, then redirect the user on that static website to another?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more? I'm pretty sure you can with AWS IoT using MQTT publishing to a topic via a javascript library.

Answer (score 0):

WeCanBeFriends,

This is possible using the Job Status Poller pattern, but tweaked slightly.  If the "Job" is to deploy the website, then the condition to "Complete Job" is to see some activity come in (ideally through cloudwatch metrics).

Once you see enough metrics to be ok with your deployment, you can either do a push notification to the webapp to inform it to redirect (using a lambda function that calls SNS - as in the wait timer sample) or have the webapp poll the execution status until it's complete.

Below I've posted a very simple variation to the Job Status Poller to illustrate my example:

[image: Send SNS When Deployment Complete]

```
{
  "Comment": "A state machine that publishes to SNS after a deployment completes.",
  "StartAt": "StartDeployment",
  "States": {
    "StartDeployment": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:012345678912:function:KickOffDeployment",
      "ResultPath": "$.guid",
      "Next": "CheckIfDeploymentComplete"
    },
    "CheckIfDeploymentComplete": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:012345678912:function:CheckIfDeploymentComplete",
      "Next": "TriggerWebAppRefresh",
      "InputPath": "$.guid",
      "ResultPath": "$.status",
      "Retry": [ {
         "ErrorEquals": [ "INPROGRESS" ],
         "IntervalSeconds": 5,
         "MaxAttempts": 240,
         "BackoffRate": 1.0
       } ],
       "Catch": [ {
            "ErrorEquals": ["FAILED"],
            "Next": "DeploymentFailed"
       }]
    },
    "DeploymentFailed": {
      "Type": "Fail",
      "Cause": "Deployment failed",
      "Error": "Deployment FAILED"
    },
    "TriggerWebAppRefresh": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:012345678912:function:SendSNSToWebapp",
      "InputPath": "$.guid",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: hi SunnyD, 

thanks for the answer, so I deploy my website and it displays some sort of text, then on some activity in dynamo, the text should change. 

Am I not right to say that once it is deployed, since it is a static website in s3, we no longer have a connection to it? So the refresh method you mentioned, would not know what to refresh?

You mentioned having the webapp poll the execution status for example, this is not possible on a static site? 

Thanks for the assistance, Sunny, massive help